# HTML/PHP Passing arguments into javascript function with onclick="" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make my Image Input pass a URL into a Javascript function using OnClick, however when I click on the input it does nothing. The code I am using is in PHP, and it echo's out a string with HTML tags in it.

```
echo "<input type=\"image\" onclick=\"imgp(\'" . $url .  "\')\" src=\"" . $url . "\" style=\"max-width: 20%; max-height: 20%\" /><br />";
```

The function that is getting called is as follows:

```
function imgp(url){
            if(url != null){
                var text = document.getElementById("body").value + "[img]" + url + "[/img]";
                document.getElementById("body").value = text;
                imgpopup();
            }
        }
```

Comment: before using echo to print the html test the function using normal html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can't test with the code you posted, try to do the following:

```
echo '<input type="image" onclick="imgp(\" . $url . '\')" src="' . $url . '" style="max-width: 20%; max-height: 20%" /><br />';
```

If you use simple quote ('), inside the echo, you can use the double quote (") without using (), but instead, you need to use only with ('), and vice-versa.

Comment: Using echo '<input type="image" onclick="imgp(\'' . $url . '\')" src="' . $url . '" style="max-width: 20%; max-height: 20%" /><br />'; Seemed to work, update your code and I'll mark it as an answer.